# can not insert document (record) into mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am developing project in MEAN STACK and I need to import countries, states and cities
From the following code.
 I can import countries and states from json files  but cities can import only first document (record) instead of all.

> **Route.js**

```
router
    .route('/api/user/loadcity')
    .get(
        function(req, res, next) {
            var fs = require("fs");
            fs.readFile('/home/user7/Downloads/city.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               console.log(data[i].city_name);
                var newCity = new City({
                    id:data[i].id,
                    country_id : data[i].country_id,
                    state_id : data[i].state_id,
                    city_name : data[i].city_name,
                    is_active : data[i].is_active
                });
                newCity.save(function (err) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
              }
            });
        });


router
    .route('/api/user/loadcountry')
    .get(
        function(req, res, next) {
            var fs = require("fs");
            fs.readFile('/home/user7/Downloads/country.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
              data = JSON.parse(data); 
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               //console.log(data[i].city_name);
                var newCountry = new Country();
                newCountry.id = data[i].id;
                newCountry.country_name = data[i].country_name;
                newCountry.country_code = data[i].country_code;
                newCountry.country_flag = data[i].country_flag;
                newCountry.is_active = data[i].is_active;
                newCountry.save(function (err) {
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                });
              }
            });
        });



router
    .route('/api/user/loadstate')
    .get(
        function(req, res, next) {
            var fs = require("fs");
            fs.readFile('/home/user7/Downloads/state.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
              data = JSON.parse(data); 
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               console.log(data[i].state_name);
                var newState = new State({
                    id:data[i].id,
                    country_id : data[i].country_id,
                    state_name : data[i].state_name,
                    is_active : data[i].is_active
                });
                newState.save(function (err) {
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                });
              }
            });
        });
```

form the above code loadcountry and loadstate routing code working properly,
but loadcity routing code can insert only one document (record).

> **dependencies**

```
country.json  => 
        file size 48.9 kB (48,883 bytes)
        total records 252
state.json    => 
        file size 362.5 kB (3,62,478 bytes)
        total records 2800
city.json     =>
       file size 21.0 MB (2,09,63,600 bytes)
        total records 142987

"express"  => "version": "4.13.4",
"mongoose" => "version": "4.4.4",
"mongodb"  => "version": "2.4.9",
"OS"  => "ubuntu 14.04 lts 32bit",
```

anybody can help me to insert these all cities.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your `country` and `state` are working fine. save being an I/O operation in mongodb is `async` in nature and for loop is `sync`.The `values` inserted will be the last item in the array.

You could use a closure to solve this one..

```
router
    .route('/api/user/loadcity')
    .get(
        function(req, res, next) {
            var fs = require("fs");
            fs.readFile('/home/user7/Downloads/city.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                   (function(i){
                    console.log(data[i].city_name);
                    var newCity = new City({
                        id: data[i].id,
                        country_id: data[i].country_id,
                        state_id: data[i].state_id,
                        city_name: data[i].city_name,
                        is_active: data[i].is_active
                    });
                    newCity.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                  })(i);                      
                }
            });
        });
```

Using `async` library

```
  async.forEach(data, function(data, callback) {

  });
```

Comment: Thanks for advice but this code also insert first document (record) only not all or  last, please give me another suggestions.

Comment: use async library and use async.forEach... this should sort you the issue